# Memory problems with smaller CNN

Tags: keras, numpy, convolutional-neural-network, tflearn

Hello everyone I'm having a weird problem.

I having problem with one of two models I've been using. Models take an image data as input and outputs joystick and keyboard information.

- [A simple CNN](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/9c689775a22f9e8647207eeae012978048d44bed/examples/mnist_cnn.py#L47), implemented using Keras to use with MNIST data, in which I changed the input size;
- The [inception_v3](https://github.com/Sentdex/pygta5/blob/efdd66841ff909a027a42ebb48facbd63670e281/models.py#L219) (which is way more complex than the first one).

While training the first model, it throws the following error:

```
> 2018-05-07 23:03:22.080446: W T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\framework\allocator.cc:101] Allocation of 1037238272 exceeds 10% of system memory.
```

I have tried changing the batch_size parameter to a smaller batch size without any results.

Comment: Your problem is with the cnn which is using MNIST?

Comment: No. I'm using image data ->X and input of joystick and keyboard->Y.

Comment: I tried in linux and it freeze but can go on after a while, so I don't know if it is because of Windows (where I was trying) or the way that keras manages the memory and data...

Comment: Have you used your image data as the input of the architecture of the second link? Have you reshaped your input? if so to which size?

Comment: If you have not resized your input image, since you have few numbers of convolution and pooling layer, the number of parameters in your dense layers can be a huge number because the outputs of convolutional layers will have a lot of activation maps.

Comment: See [this GitHub issue relating to your output](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/18736) just before the crash: apparently it is just a warning - check the system memory usage or compute the actual memory that should be used by the model, as is done in that thread. This might help at least rule out actual memory issues.

Comment: Could you add the complete resulting architecture?